# Display a text on a graph that contains both a description and a variable

Tags: r, string, histogram

I want to display on a histogram of R^2 values the mean R^2 value.
I wish to display it as "Mean = " and then the mean R^2 as a variable.

```
histogram(R_sq_vec)
text(0.2,300, 'mean =  num2str(mean(R_sq_vec))')
```

i have been trying to using th num2str command. Can anybody help?

SOLVED: i put my desired text in brackets like so:

```
text(0.25,500, ['mean = '  num2str(mean(R_sq_vec))])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `paste0()`, like this:

```
histogram(R_sq_vec)
text(0.2,300, paste0(mean = mean(R_sq_vec)))
```

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your problem.

```
R_sq_vec<-rnorm(100,20,2.3) #create data set
hist(R_sq_vec) #plot data
text(15,22,paste0("mean =",
                  round(mean(R_sq_vec),1))) #add mean value
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: i put my desired text in brackets like so:

```
text(0.25,500, ['mean = '  num2str(mean(R_sq_vec))])
```